# PHP split class function calls

Tags: php, class, object, orm, idiorm

I use PHP and [Idiorm](https://github.com/j4mie/idiorm) for SQL queries.

**A normal query**

This one works.

```
$females = ORM::for_table('person')
               ->where('gender', 'female')
               ->find_many();
```

**Problem**

In *some cases* I need to add another where-clause, **without** rewriting the whole query again. The result might look like this. It works.

```
$females = ORM::for_table('person')
               ->where('gender', 'female')
               ->where('parent', 22)
               ->find_many();
```

**My try that failed**

It somehow loses the object.

```
$females = ORM::for_table('person')
               ->where('gender', 'female');

if( ! empty( $parent ) )
{
$females->where('parent', $parent);
}

$females->find_many();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about Idiorm in particular, but you should be able to refactor that code to:

```
$query = ORM::for_table('person')->where('gender', 'female');

if ($parent) {
    $query->where('parent', $parent);
}

$females = $query->find_many();
```